# How to connect remote hive from spark with authentication

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I have to use my local spark to connect a remote hive with authentication.

I am able to connect via beeline.

> beeline> !connect jdbc:hive2://bigdatamr:10000/default
>   Connecting to jdbc:hive2://bigdatamr:10000/default
>   Enter username for jdbc:hive2://bigdatamr:10000/default: myusername
>   Enter password for jdbc:hive2://bigdatamr:10000/default: ********
>   Connected to: Apache Hive (version 1.2.0-mapr-1703)
>   Driver: Hive JDBC (version 1.2.0-mapr-1703)
>   Transaction isolation: TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ

How can I convert it to using spark?
I tried thrift and jdbc but both not working

My trift try, don't know how to pass authentication

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession\
    .builder.master("yarn")\
    .appName("my app")\
    .config("hive.metastore.uris", "thrift://bigdatamr:10000")\
    .enableHiveSupport()\
    .getOrCreate()
```

My jdbc try, throw method not support

```
jdbcDF = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:hive2://bigdatamr:10000") \
    .option("dbtable", "default.tmp") \
    .option("user", "myusername") \
    .option("password", "xxxxxxx") \
    .load()
```

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o183.load.
```

: java.sql.SQLException: Method not supported

Comment: do you have access to spark configuration on the remote cluster? i mean the directory PATH/TO/SPARK/conf ?

Comment: @user1314742 Yes, I can

Comment: can you locate a file called hive-site.xml? you copy this file locally to your spark conf directory, and try running your application again

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the driver you are using in the options of `spark.read`:

```py
.option("driver", "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver")
```

Also, for some reason you have to specify the database in the jdbc url and the name of the table with option `dbTable`. For some reason it does not work to simply define `dbTable` as `database.table`.

It would look like this:

```py
jdbcDF = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("driver", "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:hive2://bigdatamr:10000/default")
    .option("dbtable", "tmp") \
    .option("user", "myusername") \
    .option("password", "xxxxxxx") \
    .load()
```

Comment: I added but still throw the same error 
"java.sql.SQLException: Method not supported"

Comment: What version of spark are you using? Can you also try creating a simple local spark driver with `SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate()`?

Comment: I am now using spark 2.4.0. I created the simple local spark driver using your code but still throws the same error

Comment: I think you need to specify the database in the jdbc url. I updated the answer with the full code to try that. Let me know if that works

Comment: Could you provide the full stack trace?

Comment: You should be using Thrift to connect to Hive from Spark (the builtin method) not JDBC

Comment: The question was about a problem while trying to connect with jdbc. I just fixed their code. Opinion free

Comment: Were. you able to solve this problem? Trying to access remote hive metastore via thrift, but I keep getting 403 Forbidden error. Not sure where to look for this..

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this problem is a configuration problem.

If you have access to your server `/PATH/TO/HIVE/hive-site.xml` file, copy it to your local spark configuration folder `/PATH/TO/SPARK/conf/` and then retry running your application

Answer (score 0):

Replace cloudera hive jdbc driver to overwrite official jdbc. It works.

jdbc url below:
https://www.cloudera.com/downloads/connectors/hive/jdbc/2-6-15.html

I uploaded it to databricks libraries and change the connected code.

Here is my code:

```
  sql=f"SELECT * FROM  (select column from db.table where column = 'condition'"
  print(sql)
  print("\nget Hive data\n")
  spark_df = spark.read \
                .format("jdbc")\
                .option("driver", "com.cloudera.hive.jdbc41.HS2Driver") \
                .option("url", "url") \
                .option("query", "sql") \
                .load()
```

here is my blog

https://blog.8owe.com/

it mgiht helps you more.